# pandas dataframe - get a list of column names where cell has a certain value

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to get my hands on pandas DataFrames. I have constructed a certain matrix which looks like this:

```
    x   y   z
A   1   0   1
B   1   1   0
C   1   0   0
D   0   1   0
```

What I want to have is this (for each cell = 1, append the column name to the result per row):

```
A   x,z
B   x,y
C   x
D   y
```

My current best solution iterates over the columns in a for loop, gets all columns with a value > 0, extracts the column names and then passes it on to my next function. However, since I have a lot of columns (>1000) the for loop is very slow and I am sure there is a better way which I cannot figure out. Can you give me a helping hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use if there are only `1` and `0` values use matrix multiplication [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names and last remove separator by [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df['new'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df)
   x  y  z  new
A  1  0  1  x,z
B  1  1  0  x,y
C  1  0  0    x
D  0  1  0    y
```

If possible some another integers and is necessary test for greater like `0` by [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) use:

```
df['new'] = df.gt(0).dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
```